# Different between Android webview and Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

What is the difference between the Android webview and the ionic framework? Both can load content created with web technologies like HTML CSS and JavaScript. Has ionic an advantage over the Android webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android webview:

- 1) WebView have problems with support of AngularJS.
- 2) only for Android

Ionic framework:

- 1) functionality for AngularJS.
- 2) hybrid app development

In native apps usually better performance and security.

Comment: I didn't find performance test results between Android WebView and Ionic.

I want to notice that you can improve WebView performance with WebSettings.

I suppose that answer depends from specific tasks. This is false statement that one of them is always better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ionic will use best practices to give you good user experience, but both work over webview and in some situations you will have lags.